# Generating higher vertex count polygons to retain projection

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, software-recommendations, vertices

I'm displaying polygonal boundary data from a government source (VicGrid94 projection) on a Mapbox-GL-JS (EPSG 3857) map (first converting it to GeoJSON, EPSG 4326).

The client is concerned about the small distortions that happen in that conversion process: presumably although the vertices map precisely, the lines are different shapes in the different projections (so a given property might be slightly one side or the other, depending on the projection).

So I had the idea of:

1. First, generate a new version of the boundaries, with many more vertices (linearly interpolated along the existing lines).
2. Then reproject as above.

What tools can I use to do this?

I would naturally use Turf's `lineChunk` function but Turf doesn't seem to support other projections.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [`ST_Segmentize`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html) in PostGIS as a pre-processing step. You just need to decide the length of shortest segment, and this function will return a geometry or geography having no segment that is longer than this. For (multi)polygons this results in densification.